# HP E3800 series Web GUI times out

Tags: switch, hp, graphical-user-interface, hp-procurve

I am having some trouble with the web interface for my new E3800 (3800-48G-4SFP+ Switch (J9576A)). I have two of them stacked in a ring topology. When I restore to the factory default and add an IP address for my LAN to the DEFAULT_VLAN. I can connect and it works. Then after a bit of customizing the web interface stops working. I can't figure out why. My running-config is below. As you can see, I don't have any of the ports in the "back" VLAN. Any ideas? Thanks!

```
HP Stack E3800# sh run

Running configuration:

; hpStack Configuration Editor; Created on release #KA.15.03.3004
; Ver #01:00:01

hostname "HP Stack E3800"
time timezone -5
time daylight-time-rule Continental-US-and-Canada
stacking
   member 1 type "J9576A" mac-address 082e5f-68xxxx
   member 2 type "J9576A" mac-address 082e5f-68xxxx
   exit
ip default-gateway 10.0.40.254
vlan 1
   name "DEFAULT_VLAN"
   untagged 1/1-1/52,2/1-2/52
   ip address 10.0.40.247 255.255.255.0
   exit
vlan 2
   name "back"
   no ip address
   exit
ip authorized-managers 10.0.40.54 255.255.255.255 access manager
snmp-server community "public"
oobm
   member 1
      no ip address
      exit
   member 2
      no ip address
      exit
   no ip address
   ip default-gateway 10.0.40.254
   exit
vlan 1
   ipv6 mld
   exit
vlan 2
   ipv6 mld
   exit
password manager
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer!! I was configuring the OOBM interface which must automatically turn off the WebGui through the a VLAN. I needed to do the following;

disable the OOBM

enable "management-vlan 1"

Make my ip an authorized manager

```
Commands: (once in the config context)
oobm disable
management-vlan 1
ip authorized-managers myIP
```